# Queried data disappears when webpack initially loads, then appears when I go to other page on website and return

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

On the index page referenced below there is a section where I source data from a WordPress API to generate the four most recent posts from a client. When running in develop mode with Gatsby, the website is presented fine, but when I upload the website to Netlify and build it out, the data disappears and leaves nothing more than an empty set of p tags.

When I go into development tools and step through breakpoints, I notice that the data in question appears on the website, but then disappears once the webpack fires and the modules are bundled. It's almost as if this data is getting overwritten. When I navigate away from this page on the same website, and then return, the p tags HAVE the data in question. I'm assuming the webpack overwrites the initial code, and then when I come back to the page the webpack has already fired so it loads the information fine? How do I work around this? Excuse me if this is a silly/obvious question.

Full code in reference:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import indexStyles from '../components/modules/index.module.css'

import Carousel from 'nuka-carousel'
import header1 from '../img/header1.jpg'
import header2 from '../img/header2.jpg'
import header3 from '../img/header3.jpg'





const IndexPage = () => {
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allWordpressPost (sort: {fields:date, order:DESC}) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            slug
            excerpt
            date(formatString:"MMMM DD, YYYY")
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `)

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className={indexStyles.indexCarousel_container}>
                <Carousel
                    autoplay={true}
                    autoplayInterval={5000}
                    pauseOnHover={false}
                    wrapAround={true}
                    renderCenterLeftControls={({ previousSlide }) => (
                        <button onClick={previousSlide} className={indexStyles.indexCarousel_button}><i className="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
                    )}
                    renderCenterRightControls={({ nextSlide }) => (
                        <button onClick={nextSlide} className={indexStyles.indexCarousel_button}><i className="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                    )}>
                    <div className={indexStyles.indexCarousel_slideContainer}>
                        <a href="https://www.etsy.com/shop/QuestforCute" target="__blank"><img src={header1} alt="Pencil case with cat, heart, and cupcake design."></img></a>
                        <div>
                            <h2>Shop</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={indexStyles.indexCarousel_slideContainer}>
                        <Link to="/blog"><img src={header2} alt="Notepad next to a cup of coffee."></img></Link>
                        <div>
                            <h2>Blog</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={indexStyles.indexCarousel_slideContainer}>
                        <a href="https://etsy.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=51a896ffcc9959f46b93e215a&id=d52a3c39d8" target="__blank"><img src={header3} alt="Colorful pencil cases."></img></a>
                        <div>
                            <h2>Cute Castle VIP</h2>
                            <p>Save 20%!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Carousel>
            </div>
            <h1 className={indexStyles.indexHeader}>Latest Posts</h1>
            <div className={indexStyles.indexPost_container}>
                <div className={indexStyles.indexPost_container}>
                    {data.allWordpressPost.edges.map((edge, i) => {
                        if (i < 4) {
                            return (
                                <div className={indexStyles.index_post}>
                                    <h2><Link to={`/blog/${edge.node.slug}`} className={indexStyles.post_title} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: edge.node.title }}></Link></h2>
                                    <p className={indexStyles.post_date}>{edge.node.date}</p>
                                    <p className={indexStyles.post_excerpt} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: edge.node.excerpt }} />
                                    <p><Link to={`/blog/${edge.node.slug}`} className={indexStyles.post_link}>Read more</Link></p>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>


        </Layout >
    )
}

export default IndexPage
```

The section of code that disappears and reappears:

```
<div className={indexStyles.indexPost_container}>
                <div className={indexStyles.indexPost_container}>
                    {data.allWordpressPost.edges.map((edge, i) => {
                        if (i < 4) {
                            return (
                                <div className={indexStyles.index_post}>
                                    <h2><Link to={`/blog/${edge.node.slug}`} className={indexStyles.post_title} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: edge.node.title }}></Link></h2>
                                    <p className={indexStyles.post_date}>{edge.node.date}</p>
                                    <p className={indexStyles.post_excerpt} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: edge.node.excerpt }} />
                                    <p><Link to={`/blog/${edge.node.slug}`} className={indexStyles.post_link}>Read more</Link></p>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
```

A link to the Netlify project.

https://zealous-engelbart-509321.netlify.com/

Thanks in advance for your help!